# How YARN cluster metrics are calculated ? Are they an instant snapshot or an average over a period?

Tags: performance, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, metrics

For example, by executing this:
http://:8088/ws/v1/cluster/metrics

I get an output like this:

```
{
    "clusterMetrics": {
        "appsSubmitted": 502521,
        "appsCompleted": 501201,
        "appsPending": 0,
        "appsRunning": 19,
        "appsFailed": 454,
        "appsKilled": 847,
        "reservedMB": 140400,
        "availableMB": 12615232,
        "allocatedMB": 8830800,
        "reservedVirtualCores": 39,
        "availableVirtualCores": 6140,
        "allocatedVirtualCores": 2065,
        "containersAllocated": 1692,
        "containersReserved": 39,
        "containersPending": 3960,
        "totalMB": 21446032,
        "totalVirtualCores": 8205,
        "totalNodes": 199,
        "lostNodes": 1,
        "unhealthyNodes": 1,
        "decommissionedNodes": 8,
        "rebootedNodes": 0,
        "activeNodes": 189
    }
}
```

For instance, allocatedMB means what ? 
Is it an instantaneous value ? 
Is it averaged over an interval period ? The interval is configurable ?

Answer (score 0):

The allocatedMB is the memory that has been assigned to the vcores (though not necessarily used).  Yes, it is an instantaneous value.  There is no interval, it's a snapshot of your cluster at that instant (minus the time it takes to compute these values from the data structures in the Resource Manager and then return it via the REST API).

If you want to translate your metrics it's saying:

- You currently have 19 apps running.
- These 19 apps are using a total of 2065 vcores.
- These 2065 vcores have reserved 8830800 MB of memory for them